# link_to model with binary uuid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, uuid

I'm using uuid for my models who will have comments. I do this so i don't have to define any types in my comments table.

For best performance and storage limits i have my uuid as binary in my tabel.

```
> Task.first.id
# gives
\xD8<\x92&\x14\x80\x11\xE2\x82\xB8\xC4\x85\b\"\xE2_
```

If I use for example:

```
<%= link_to "task", task_item %>
```

I will not get any valid link.

```
<a href="http://localhost:3000/tasks/%D8X%C4n%14%80%11%E2%82%B8%C4%85%08%22%E2_">Task</a>
```

**And my question is. What can i do to my model so i don't have to parse my uuid back-and-forth every time in my views and my controllers.**

*Edit: Please don't comment or answer that i shood not have an uuid as primary key. My goal is to have more than one web app and other clients like native linux and/or android apps that communicates with each other. They may also work in offline mode or over lokal network and then sync with server when user wants to. So I rather start using uuid already so i don't have to make alot of big database merges later.*

Comment: Maybe use a normal integer field for your `id`?

Comment: Seems like "best performance and storage limits" is a premature optimization. Not to mention how can a binary UUID be more performant than an integer id?

Comment: I meant that i will have the best performance I can get from an uuid.

Comment: i don't get why you would have to *parse* anything?! where is the parsing in your example?